# What command can I use to clear the 'yum' cache, on Fedora 23 system?

Tags: fedora, yum, cache

What command can I use to clear the `yum` cache on a Fedora 23 system? 
I have tried `yum clean all`, but it defaults to:

```
Redirecting to '/usr/bin/dnf clean all' (see 'man yum2dnf')
```

with "0 files removed"

Comment: It's possible that you simply don't have any files in your cache to clear.  Is there anything that leads you to believe you have packages, metadata, or anything else in your cache?

Comment: Yes, I ran a disk usage analyzer and found that /var/cache/yum contained the sub-directory /x86_64/23 that contains 287 items storing 1.4 GB of data.

Comment: Lucky you my /var/cache/yum weighs 22G: 4.5G for /26/ and 12G for /27/. There's also an almost empty /28/ directory, weird.

Comment: I have seen similar to that too. Now I manage a lot of that disk space using BleachBit, and run it via Terminal as root. It cleans most all the common cache builders, plus the system files too.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

According to the [documentation for `dnf clean`](http://dnf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command_ref.html#clean-command-label):

> Performs cleanup of temporary files kept for repositories. This includes any such data left behind from disabled or removed repositories as well as for different distribution release versions.
>
> ```
> dnf clean dbcache
> ```
>
> Removes cache files generated from the repository metadata. This forces  DNF to regenerate the cache files the next time it is run.
>
> ```
> dnf clean expire-cache
> ```
>
> Marks the repository metadata expired. DNF will re-validate the cache for each repo the next time it is used.
>
> ```
> dnf clean metadata
> ```
>
> Removes repository metadata. Those are the files which DNF uses to determine the remote availability of packages. Using this option will make DNF download all the metadata the next time it is run.
>
> ```
> dnf clean packages
> ```
>
> Removes any cached packages from the system.
>
> ```
> dnf clean all
> ```
>
> Does all of the above.

So if `dnf clean all` did not clean it up, then it's not part of the dnf cache.  The dnf cache lives in `/var/cache/dnf`; `/var/cache/yum` may be leftover from a previous version of Fedora (prior to the upgrade from yum to dnf), and you can almost certainly remove the files in that directory safely.

Comment: I have found, actually reminded recently that _Bleach Bit_ (http://www.bleachbit.org/) does and excellent job on finding/cleaning out system clutter.